# I cannot figure out how to use the SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserNameByEmail Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

This is a MVC 4 Internet application.  I have set the Role Provider and Role Manager to SimpleRoleProvider and SimpleMembershipProvider in the Web.config file, but I continue to get the "You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class" exception despite initializing WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection in the Global,asax.cs file.  I know this was initialized properly because the Roles property in the Authorize Attribute I have created and assign programmatically work perfect.  All I want to do is retrieve a Users UserName and email it to them if they forget and cannot login.  Advice appreciated.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [CaptchaVerify("Captcha is not valid")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ForgotUserNameOrPassword(UserProfile model, FormCollection collection)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "The Captcha answer is incorrect";
            return View();
        }
        else
        {


            SimpleMembershipProvider mySMP = new SimpleMembershipProvider();

            int outRecs;

            dynamic email = new Postal.Email("UserNameEmail");


            MembershipUserCollection myUserCol =mySMP.FindUsersByEmail(model.UserEmail, 0, 0, out outRecs);

            email.Username = myUserCol;
            email.To = model.UserEmail;
            email.From = model.UserEmail;
            email.Send();

            return View("../Account/Login");

        }
    }
```

Comment: You do not instantiate SimpleMembershipProvider that way.  You just say Membership.Provider, and this gives you the already instantiated provider.  However, Your problem beyond that is that those methods are not implemented by SimpleMembershipProvider.  So you will have to simply query the database manually.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you did call InitializeDatabaseConnection properly it would not work for [SimpleMembershipProvider.FindUsersByEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.findusersbyemail%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).  Here is a note in the documentation for this method.

> If the SimpleMembershipProvider class has been initialized using a call to the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection() method, this method is not supported and will throw a NotSupportedException exception. However, if the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection() method has not been called, and if you have configured your site to use the standard ASP.NET membership provider, this method is passed through to the standard membership provider. For more information, see the SimpleMembershipProvider class overview.

What you are experiencing does not make any sense given the documentation. Where exactly is the exception being thrown? When you call FindUsersByEmail?

**Updated 6/28/13**

SimpleMembershipProvider does not implement all of the standard provider methods. If a method is missing you have a couple of options.  First you can create your own custom SimpleMembershipProvider that is derived from the original that has the methods you need. Or you can extend the WebSecurity class to include the methods you need.  Take a look at the [SimpleSecurity](http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/) open source project which [decouples SimpleMembership from the ASP.NET MVC application](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/03/decoupling-simplemembership-from-your.html). This [article describes how to extend the WebSecurity class](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/04/retrieving-confirmation-token-in.html) and queries the database directly. You can do something similar and query for a particular user by their email address.

But SimpleMembership does not support storing the users email address out-of-the-box. Take a look at this [article on how to customize SimpleMembership to include the email address](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html).

Also keep in mind that the reason that the base membership provider returns multiple users for an email address is that the schema does not restrict a user from opening multiple accounts with the same email address, unless the email address is used as the username.

Comment: The FindUsernameByEmail call was incorrect from the beginning because it brings in a collection of Usernames rather than the specific Username I need to email the user.  I am now using the Membership.GetUserNameByEmail call by passing the model.UserEmail to its parameters and setting that to the email.UserNmame.  The exception I am getting is that "Specified method is not supported." because that is a method that belongs to MembershipProvider.  I want to use SimpleMembershipProvider, but gain access to some of the methods in Membership Provider.

Comment: The exception occurs when I call Membership.GetUserByEmail().